# how to change the block status to insert in 10g using a button trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, developer-tools

how to change the block or form status to 'insert' in oracle forms 10g using when-button-pressed trigger. I want to do the same thing like the 'insert record' button in the default tool bar but using a custom button

any ideas?

Comment: 'insert' is not a valid block or form status - only records can be marked for insert. The form can be in 'changed' status though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `do_key('create_record');` in your when-button-pressed trigger. This will insert a new record in the current block with all, what state changes accordingly.

Changing the state with `set_record_property(:system.cursor_record, :system.cursor_block, state, 'INSERT');` will not bring the exact same result. But give it a try!