# Oracle forms record status

Tags: oracle, plsql, record, status, oracleforms

I have an issue that I need to figure out. We're using Oracle forms 6. I've got detailed view of a record in block `B2` with some fields in it. User is able to create and update that record. But in this block I've got also a button with trigger `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` on it. When user press the button it goes to another block called `B4` and executes query. When there are some filled fields in block `B2` I have to change record property in `B2`. Block `B4` opens a new window with canvas in it. User is able to go back to block `B2` by pressing escape key, close button and by save button. The thing is, that I'm not able to change the record_status back to the state before leaving block `B2`.

Code sample:

```
/*
 B2 OPEN_BTN WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED
*/
set_record_property(:system.trigger_record, 'B2', STATUS, QUERY_STATUS);
go_block('B4');
execute_query;


/*
 B4 PRE-QUERY
*/
--do some stuff (set_default_where, ...)


/*
  User modifies one of the records without commit
*/


/*
 B4 SAVE_BTN - WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED
*/
--assign values to the fields of block B2
go_block('b2');
--change the record status back to it's default (INSERT/CHANGED) - but how?
--I've tried many things and I got sometimes alerts of 
--invalid change from CHANGED to INSERT etc.
```

Thanks for your help! All should be done without any prompt to save the record.

Comment: There is another topic about this, can be helpful for you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131046/how-to-change-the-block-status-to-insert-in-10g-using-a-button-trigger

Comment: I think before you navigate to the other block you just need to call `clear_block`, possibly `clear_block(no_commit)` but it's been a while since I've done forms.

Comment: Yes, I've accomplished that by remebering previous record status and by changing it to the previous state.